Alignment and anti-alignment of spins in magnetic field
Let's say that we spins in a very strong magnetic field. Then, the spins want to align in the same direction as the magnetic field due to torque being exerted on the spins. However, it may happen that due to thermal excitations in the material, spins can be excited such that they point anti-parallel to the magnetic field. Then, there is no torque exerted and the spins remain anti-parallel to the magnetic field.
Now, if we introduce a small perturbation to the anti-aligned spin so that it isn't perfectly anti-aligned anymore, will it completely rotate until it is aligned in the same direction as the magnetic field again? (Again, assuming the magnetic field is very strong)
In principle, there are always thermal excitations that act as small perturbations. How is it then possible that spins can be anti aligned? Maybe in the limit that the magnetic field goes to infinity the spins will always point in the same direction as the magnetic field if there are also thermal excitations?
Note: align in the same direction = pointing in the same direction

Can you possibly provide some more context?  For instance, is there some particular magnetic material you are referencing?

A few points have to be addressed:

You do not have to specify the field as being very strong, these questions are valid for any value of the field (and the answers do not change!)
If the spin happens to be exactly anti-parallel to the magnetic field, there is indeed no torque exerted, but in QM that does not mean it will remain anti-parallel to the magnetic field. Classically this may be true (balancing as an upside-down pencil on its tip) but quantum mechanically there does not exist such an eternal equilibrium.
So in QM you do not have to introduce a small perturbation to get the spin back aligned again (but you are free to do so of course). And in any case it will indeed fully rotate back to the aligned position, while undergoing precession around the magnetic axis, which will be responsible for EM wave emission (and thus for conservation of energy!)
So the question may become: (although you didn't ask it yet) why can there be an (unstable) anti-aligned equilibrium in the classical case, but not in QM?!
A) Classically the differential equation clearly has two equilibrium solutions, aligned and anti-aligned, both of which do not have precession (since there is no torque) so they do not emit EM waves and remain constant in time.
B) In QM, you could try to find the Hamiltonian for a spin-$\frac12$ that couples to the EM field. Deriving that is a bit outside the scope of this question (although it can be done quite simply in a resonant cavity, where only one photon mode is contributing, a case which classically would still give a perfectly stationary anti-aligned solution!) But the following reasoning is also possible. Suppose the spin-up and spin-down state would both be stationary, then there would be eigenstates of the Hamiltonian
$$
 H\,  |\!\uparrow\rangle_e|A\rangle_\phi = E_+ |\!\uparrow\rangle_e|A\rangle_\phi
\\[7pt]
 H\,  |\!\downarrow\rangle_e|B\rangle_\phi = E_- |\!\downarrow\rangle_e|B\rangle_\phi
$$
These should be seen as "dressed up" states, where the $|\rangle_e$ states are for the spin-$1/2$, while $|A\rangle_\phi$ and $|B\rangle_\phi$ denote states of the photon field.
But that would mean that for every combination of these states we would have the time dependent solution:
$$
|\psi(t)\rangle = \,
\alpha\ e^{-iE_+/\hbar}\ |\!\uparrow\rangle_e|A\rangle_\phi
+
\beta\ e^{-iE_-/\hbar}\  |\!\downarrow\rangle_e|B\rangle_\phi
$$
and we know that by choosing $(\alpha,\beta)$ we can put the spin in any direction, and in the solution $|\psi(t)\rangle$ it would remain precessing forever, with frequency $(E_+-E_-)/\hbar$, apparently without radiating energy, so it would not be coupled to the EM field at all. Or stated differently: if we do have any coupling to the EM field, then at least one of the eigenstates must not exist (and we know of course that only the ground state will still exist).


Thanks a lot for your extensive answer! I am wondering in the time dependent wave function, how does this linear combination imply precession (with that frequency) around the magnetic field? It just means that it exists in a superposition right? And where does the time dependence sit on the RHS? Also I am wondering, how in NMR do we then assume thst there are anti aligned spins since it's an unstable equilibrium classically and not an eigenstate in QM?

These questions would require a more explicit analysis (and explicitly solving would be more instructuve anyway than this proof by contradiction! But maybe that's for later.) Here it may be safer to just conclude that the existence of the intermediate state $|\psi(t)\rangle$ where we have an intermediate expectation value of the energy that does not decay further, gives a contradiction... And finally, based on all this you indeed cannot assume that there are anti-aligned spins that remain in existence forever.
